# How to two column (same table) references to a single column of other table

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa

I am new in Stack overflow forum. This is my first question.
I am creating web application using spring mvc with jpa. But I can't over come with this situation as I want both side relationship in entity model. Sorry for my bad English.
[Database Structure and data for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxdLO.jpg)

Comment: I think, I am unable to explain the actual problem so, I attach the problem photo. [link]( https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxdLO.jpg)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxdLO.jpg .Please check this link for database schema and data references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question you want to have a table free product which have withId,toId but both pointing to the same table Product.

In that case, design your Free Product table like below.

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "withId")
private Product withProduct;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "toId")
private Product toProduct;
```

Comment: Please check this link for database schema and data references.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxdLO.jpg

Comment: I think, I am unable to explain the actual problem so, I attach the problem photo.  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxdLO.jpg)

Comment: Thank you very much.. But I want both side relationship, So, what should I do in "Product" entity.

Comment: In that case do the same inside Product entity. Or try with mappedBy https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-onetomany-bidirectional-relationship/